# Rebuild all ports after FreeBSD upgrade

Tags: freebsd, upgrade

I have just upgraded from 10.3 to 11.1. [The following page](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/updating-upgrading-freebsdupdate.html#freebsdupdate-portsrebuild) describes the recommended next steps

When I run `portmaster -af` I am continuously prompted for questions about what should be built for each package. How do I simple take the default selection for each one automatically? There is no way this process will ever complete otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just assume "yes" to everything, temporally you may add to `/etc/make.conf` this:

```
BATCH=yes
```

see also this https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5905/53084

Answer (score 9):

`portmaster -afdy --no-confirm`

---

**It's** generally good practice to peruse the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=portmaster&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE+and+Ports).

Specifically, this tidbit

> **--no-confirm**
>
> do not ask the    user to confirm the list of ports to be installed
>    and/or updated before proceeding

Unfortunately, , this is not always sufficient, especially if certain packages ask for a prompt independently.

There is another flag,  `-y` that answers yes to all prompts, depending on the version of `portmaster` it may be there, but it is absent in the FreeBSD version of the man page.

But from the [horses mouth](https://github.com/freebsd/portmaster/blob/fcad1ab333f5255054e5dfbf65c5c187fdb1a79c/portmaster#L523)

```
echo '-y answer yes to all user prompts for the features below'
```

This is actually quite common for interactive console applications across the *NIX world, so `-y` is usually worth a try.

---

**Generically**, in other situations, `yes` is a standard shell utility that will spam "yes", or any other string to a shell.

`yes | portmaster -af`

or

`yes no | portmaster -af`

to refuse everything.

Comment: I'd also add `-d` to delete old distfiles. `portmaster` asks about these and don't account `-y` for it.